# How to find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a^{n^2}}\cdot z^n$ with $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> How to find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a^{n^2}}\cdot z^n$ with $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

I have attempted to use the "root test":
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a^{n^2}}}=\frac{1}{a^n}$$ So it does converge for $a>0$, is that valid though since $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What does $\;a^{n^2}\;$ mean? Shouldn't the general term of the series have some subindex? Because that looks like a power series in $\;z\;$ ...

Comment: [The title is not the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144), so closing as unclear.

Comment: I really don't know. But I suppose Jack's right.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: when applying the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), one should take $\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ instead of $\sqrt[n]{c_n}$ in general.

Comment: What happens when $a = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem),

$$
\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|},\quad c_n=a^{n^2},\tag{1}
$$
where $R$ is the radius of convergence and we use the convention in this context that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ and $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$.

As you observed, 
$$
\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=|a|^n.
$$
Thus
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}|a|^n=\begin{cases}
0,&|a|<1\\
1,&|a|=1\\
\infty,&|a|>1.
\end{cases}
$$
Now you can apply (1) to find the radius of convergence, which depends on the absolute value of the fixed complex number $a$.